# Why is my CSS not being processed properly?

Tags: css

Why is this code (which is from W3Schools):

```css
#snackbar {
    visibility: hidden; /* Hidden by default. Visible on click */
    min-width: 250px; /* Set a default minimum width */
    margin-left: -125px; /* Divide value of min-width by 2 */
    background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
    color: #fff; /* White text color */
    text-align: center; /* Centered text */
    border-radius: 2px; /* Rounded borders */
    padding: 16px; /* Padding */
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the screen */
    z-index: 1; /* Add a z-index if needed */
    left: 50%; /* Center the snackbar */
    bottom: 30px; /* 30px from the bottom */
}
```

displaying like this in Microsoft Edge: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvcfm.jpg)

Sorry if I am missing something obvious. The CSS code is on 000Webhost

Answer (score 1):

In IE and even Edge (Big Brother), you cannot copy paste the css from anywhere else, It will interpret whole pair of "key: value" as it is the key only. Instead, if you want to add some css only to browser preview(inspect mode) add the property(key) and press enter, then only the browser expect the value for that property(key).

Comment: I didn't paste it into ME, it is hosted on 000webhost. Sorry for not saying that

Comment: Can you show the html part where you include the css? (link tag from head)

Comment: It is not from a <link> tag it is just directly in a <style> tag

Comment: did you define it in <head>? and does it have a type specified? (as "<style type="text/css">")

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have solved the problem myself!